# Why would a TextBlock with DropShadowEffect show a solid black background on one XP machine?

Tags: wpf, xaml, rendering, themes, shadow

We have a **WPF** application in which we have the following XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="HeaderRightSubtitle"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="top"
        FontSize="10"
        Foreground="#FFFFFF">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect
                Color="#FFCACACA"
                ShadowDepth="1"
                Opacity="100"
                RenderingBias="Quality"/>
        </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
```

It shows a nice **shadow** on all machines (XP, Vista) except for one **XP** machine on which is shows the white text on a solid, back, **rectangle** background also a bit offset. The XP has the same **theme** as the other machines.

**Has anyone experienced this? What could be causing the DropShadowEffect to produce a solid black background on this one machine?**

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of .Net installed on the XP Machine. You might be missing SP2 for 3.0 or SP1 for 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

What video card is in the machine and are you using the latest version of drivers? Also, what version of DirectX is installed? If I had to guess, it's something with the card/drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. It was due to an old nVidia card (FX5200 if I remember correctly). After extensive research I finally found out that nVidia fixed the bug in a newer driver, but that driver wasn't provided for the video card, because it was too old (legacy). So the only options were to either not use DropShadowEffect or buy a new card.